# How to get a pointer to the last element in a slice using Rust?

Tags: rust

I would like to get rid of the cast to isize in the example below:

```
let s = &[1, 2, 3];
let mut i = s.as_ptr();
unsafe {
    let mut j = i.offset(s.len() as isize - 1);
    do pointer arithmetic on i and j...
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I've been looking in the Rust reference for something in the vein of `s.last_as_ptr()` but have not found it.

EDIT: I should have read the pointer basics first https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/raw-pointers.html

> This is absolutely something you do not need unsafe for. If you really truly need a pointer and not a reference, you can cast the resulting reference to a pointer. – Shepmaster

@Shepmaster & @Josh Lee: I should have provided a complete example, I need to do pointer arithmetic on `i` and `j`. I edited the code to reflect this.
Thanks for pointing out .last(), that seems to be the obvious choice since it returns a reference.
The information I was missing when posting this question was that references/borrows can be cast to pointers.

This seem to be what I was looking for `let mut j = s.last().unwrap() as *const _;`

Comment: What's wrong with `.last()`?

Comment: This is absolutely something you do **not** need `unsafe for`. If you really truly need a *pointer* and not a *reference*, you can cast the resulting reference to a pointer.